# Can two deferred expressions be used in one attribute of a component in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

`<p:dialog id="mDialog" header="#{lBean.id} #{dBean.value}"> </p:dialog>`

Can we write the above evaluation expressions, in the case of header,  where two deferred evaluation expressions being used in one attribute of a component in JSF ?

Comment: What problem exactly did you face when doing so? That would be the question of interest. Stack Overflow is not the right place for rhetorical questions and questions which could be answered by simply trying out yourself.

Comment: The value from the second bean reference is not getting picked up. That's why I was wondering whether JSF allows these kind of expressions.

Comment: Apparently it's simply empty or null. Or is it working when you use `header="#{dBean.value}"`? Or does the same expression fail on all other output attributes such as a simple `<h:outputText value>`?